# Adding a downloaded library to project

Tags: clion

I downloaded the libvorbis library, but I don't understand how to implement it in my project. I tried using Cygwin, but I still get:

```
fatal error: vorbis/codec.h: No such file or directory
```

when I try to use the library.

I've also searched for terminal commands to directly install the libvorbis package, and CMake to try and use it, but I still can't figure it out.

Any tips?

Comment: Add it to the include path with the `-I` flag.

Comment: Have you alsoinstalled the -dev package?

Comment: i finally managed to figure it out after a few days, i learned how to manage the sfml library from their page and it helped a lot